# How to create an R data frame from an xml file?

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML Document file. The part of the file looks like this:

```
-<attr>  
     <attrlabl>COUNTY</attrlabl>  
     <attrdef>County abbreviation</attrdef>  
     <attrtype>Text</attrtype>  
     <attwidth>1</attwidth>  
     <atnumdec>0</atnumdec>  
    -<attrdomv>  
        -<edom>  
            <edomv>C</edomv>  
            <edomvd>Clackamas County</edomvd>  
            <edomvds/>  
         </edom>  
        -<edom>  
            <edomv>M</edomv>  
            <edomvd>Multnomah County</edomvd>  
            <edomvds/>  
         </edom>  
        -<edom>  
            <edomv>W</edomv>  
            <edomvd>Washington County</edomvd>  
            <edomvds/>  
         </edom>  
     </attrdomv>  
 </attr>
```

From this XML file, I want to create an R data frame with the columns of `attrlabl`, `attrdef`, `attrtype`, and `attrdomv`. Please note that the `attrdomv` column should include all of the levels for the category variable. The data frame should look like this:

```r
attrlabl    attrdef                attrtype    attrdomv  
COUNTY      County abbreviation    Text        C Clackamas County; M Multnomah County; W Washington County
```

I have an incomplete code like this:

```r
doc <- xmlParse("taxlots.shp.xml")  
dataDictionary <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc,"//attrlabl"))
```

Could you please complete my R code? I appreciate any help!

Comment: can you give a valid xml file please?

Comment: @agstudy: could you please tell me how to send my xml file to you?

Comment: you can't here, but you can use a file upload service like SkyDrive and post the link <a href="http://file">file</a>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming this is the correct `taxlots.shp.xml` file:

```
<attr>  
     <attrlabl>COUNTY</attrlabl>  
     <attrdef>County abbreviation</attrdef>  
     <attrtype>Text</attrtype>  
     <attwidth>1</attwidth>  
     <atnumdec>0</atnumdec>  
    <attrdomv>  
        <edom>  
            <edomv>C</edomv>  
            <edomvd>Clackamas County</edomvd>  
            <edomvds/>  
         </edom>  
        <edom>  
            <edomv>M</edomv>  
            <edomvd>Multnomah County</edomvd>  
            <edomvds/>  
         </edom>  
        <edom>  
            <edomv>W</edomv>  
            <edomvd>Washington County</edomvd>  
            <edomvds/>  
         </edom>  
     </attrdomv>  
 </attr>
```

You were almost there:

```r
doc <- xmlParse("taxlots.shp.xml")
xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc1,"//attr"))[c("attrlabl","attrdef","attrtype","attrdomv")]
  attrlabl             attrdef attrtype                                             attrdomv
1   COUNTY County abbreviation     Text CClackamas CountyMMultnomah CountyWWashington County
```

But the last field has not the format you wanted. To do so, require some additional steps:

```r
step1 <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc1,"//attrdomv/edom"))
step1
  edomv            edomvd edomvds
1     C  Clackamas County        
2     M  Multnomah County        
3     W Washington County  

step2 <- paste(paste(step1$edomv, step1$edomvd, sep=" "), collapse="; ")
step2
[1] "C Clackamas County; M Multnomah County; W Washington County"

cbind(xmlToDataFrame(nodes= getNodeSet(doc1, "//attr"))[c("attrlabl", "attrdef", "attrtype")],
      attrdomv= step2)
  attrlabl             attrdef attrtype                                                      attrdomv
1   COUNTY County abbreviation     Text C Clackamas County; M Multnomah County; W Washington County
```