# Reading XML data in R

Tags: xml, r

I'm trying to read this [file](http://data.mcc.gov/raw/xml/MCC_HN.xml) in R. I tried to use `XML package`, but I have no idea what is in the data set and I haven't used the package before.

I'd appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks.

Sebastián.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame

Answer (score 4):

There's no way around it - you need to understand XML and XPath to use it in R. Assuming you do, view the document in a browser to get an idea of its structure. Then, this should get you started using the XML package.

```
library(XML)
xml <- xmlParse("http://data.mcc.gov/raw/xml/MCC_HN.xml")

org        <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/reporting-org",xmlValue)
id         <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/iati-identifier",xmlValue)
title      <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/title",xmlValue)
desc.1     <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/description[@type='1']",xmlValue)
desc.2     <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/description[@type='2']",xmlValue)
status     <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/activity-status",xmlValue)
start.planned <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/activity-date[@type='start-planned']",xmlValue)
start.actual  <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/activity-date[@type='start-actual']",xmlValue)
end.planned   <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/activity-date[@type='end-planned']",xmlValue)
end.actual    <- xpathApply(xml,"//iati-activity/activity-date[@type='end-actual']",xmlValue)

df <- data.frame(cbind(org,id, title, status, 
                       start.planned, start.actual, end.planned, end.actual,
                       desc.1, desc.2))
```

Read the documentation on the functions I've used above, e.g. `xmlParse(...)`, `xpathApply(...)`, and `xmlValue(...)` to figure out what the code is doing.

One note: there is a function `xmlToDataFrame(...)` in the XML package. The problem with your document is that you have multiple elements with the same tag name (examples: `description` and `activity-date`), which are disambiguated using the `type=` attribute. `xmlToDataFrame(...)` doesn't know how to deal with that, so you need to do it the hard way...

Comment: How did you do to know what variables are inside the XML data? You're help was very handy. Thanks!

Comment: You need to view the file in a browser, basically. There are programmatic ways to view a list of tag names, but viewing in a browser is easiest.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want to do with the data, but here we get it

```
xml = xmlParse("http://data.mcc.gov/raw/xml/MCC_HN.xml")
```

Then query the result for all "transaction" records and make them into a data frame

```
df <- xmlToDataFrame(xml["//transaction"])
```

with

```
> dim(df)
[1] 730  11
> head(df, 2)
  aid-type
1         
2         
                                                                description
1   Commitment: Honduras-614G Fund-Not Applicable-Not Applicable-2011-04-01
2 Disbursement: Honduras-614G Fund-Not Applicable-Not Applicable-2011-04-01
  disbursement-channel finance-code flow-type                     provider-org
1                                             Millennium Challenge Corporation
2                                             Millennium Challenge Corporation
  receiver-org tied-status transaction-date transaction-type     value
1     Honduras                   2011-04-01       COMMITMENT 274380.75
2     Honduras                   2011-04-01     DISBURSEMENT      0.00
```

Maybe you'd like to extract the attribute associated with 'aid-type' and add it to the data frame; use XPath to do so

```
df$`aid-type-code` <- as.character(xml["//aid-type/@code"])
```