# Can't Extract Data from XML using R

Tags: xml, r, parsing, data-structures

So I know this topic has been discussed extensively on here. I've found quite a few questions on the same thing but still can't figure out how to parse this XML file. I'm using **R** and I want to pull the longitude and latitude from the file.

[I'm using this data](http://www.donatingplasma.org/index.php?option=com_storelocator&format=feed&searchall=1&Itemid=166&catid=-1&tagid=-1&featstate=0) and [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame) but can't seem to make it work.

**Here's what I do:**

```
require(XML)  
data <- xmlParse("http://www.donatingplasma.org/index.php?option=com_storelocator&format=feed&searchall=1&Itemid=166&catid=-1&tagid=-1&featstate=0")
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
```

That all works fine. The XML file is now a "large list." When I try to extract the latitude and longitude, I'm lost. I tried:

```
location <- as.list(xml_data[["marker"]][["lat"]])
```

And got a list with 1 row.

How would I go about pulling the latitude and longitude from this XML data?

**Sample of data structure:**

```
<markers>
<limited>0</limited>
<marker>
<name>ADMA BioCenters</name>
<category>IQPP Certified</category>
<markertype>
/media/com_storelocator/markers/100713214004000000jl_marker2.png
</markertype>
<featured>false</featured>
<address>
6290 Jimmy Carter Boulevard, Suite 208, Norcross, Georgia 30071
</address>
<lat>33.9290629</lat>
<lng>-84.2204952</lng>
<distance>0</distance>
<fulladdress>
<![CDATA[
<p><img style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/jl_marker2.png" alt="jl marker2" width="22" height="22" />IQPP Certified</p>
]]>
</fulladdress>
<phone>678-495-5800</phone>
<url>http://www.atlantaplasma.com</url>
<email/>
<facebook/>
<twitter/>
<tags>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</tags>
<custom1 name="Custom Field 1">
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</custom1>
<custom2 name="Custom Field 2">
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</custom2>
<custom3 name="Custom Field 3">
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</custom3>
<custom4 name="Custom Field 4">
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</custom4>
<custom5 name="Custom Field 5">
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</custom5>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xpathSapply` on the original XML rather than going through the list.

```
lat <- xpathSApply(data, '//marker/lat', xmlValue)
long <- xpathSApply(data, '//marker/lng', xmlValue)
```

Result:

```
> head(cbind(lat, long))
     lat          long         
[1,] "33.9290629" "-84.2204952"
[2,] "48.3097292" "14.299297"  
[3,] "41.6134569" "-87.514584" 
[4,] "41.5878273" "-87.3369907"
[5,] "39.98504"   "-83.004705" 
[6,] "43.2056277" "-86.2708023"
```

Based on @Martin Morgan's comment, I thought it would be good to benchmark different strategies here:

```
> microbenchmark(xpathSApply(data, '//marker/lat', xmlValue),
                 sapply(data["//marker/lat"], xmlValue),
                 sapply(data["//marker/lat"], as, "numeric"))
Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr       min        lq   median       uq      max neval
 xpathSApply(data, "//marker/lat", xmlValue)  67.03714  97.57796 100.1633 102.1815 213.3031   100
      sapply(data["//marker/lat"], xmlValue)  72.73847 103.63095 106.1037 108.2251 132.6314   100
 sapply(data["//marker/lat"], as, "numeric") 257.16364 346.13708 389.3025 394.3669 598.3736   100
```

Seems like

Clearly, the last strategy is least efficient (which makes sense because it's invoking type conversion on each node. But that makes it not a completely fair test since the last expression yields numeric output while the first two yield character output. Thus a second tests:

```
> microbenchmark(as.numeric(xpathSApply(data, '//marker/lat', xmlValue)), 
                 as.numeric(sapply(data["//marker/lat"], xmlValue)), 
                 sapply(data["//marker/lat"], as, "numeric"))
Unit: milliseconds
                                                    expr       min        lq    median       uq      max neval
 as.numeric(xpathSApply(data, "//marker/lat", xmlValue))  60.29744  80.08186  97.94924 100.9548 189.0797   100
      as.numeric(sapply(data["//marker/lat"], xmlValue))  59.45891  85.47169 103.68015 106.5882 124.5708   100
             sapply(data["//marker/lat"], as, "numeric") 210.92816 339.54831 384.28481 392.0001 481.4498   100
```

Again, using either `xpathSApply` or `sapply` (with an xpath extraction) yield really similar results. So a modified version of Martin's first solution:

```
lat <- as.numeric(sapply(data["//marker/lat"], xmlValue))
```

may be the best strategy here.

Comment: @RossWardrup XML in R is a real pain unless you work with xpath, when it suddenly - possibly magically - becomes much much easier.

Comment: Maybe a little more succinctly, using the notion that the xpath can subset the data object `sapply(data["//marker/lat"], xmlValue)` or using the coerction form as(x, "numeric") `sapply(data["//marker/lat"], as, "numeric")`