# R: How to extract XML tags from an XML file?

Tags: xml, r

Given an XML file, I would like to extract its corresponding XML tags. For example, if you consider an XML file like the followings:

```
<a> <b> </b> </a> <c> </c>
```

I like to extract a, b, c?
How should I do that in R?
I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame) post, but wasn't much helpful for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(XML)
text <- "<a> <b> </b> </a> <c> </c>"
xml  <- xmlParseString(text)
a    <- getNodeSet(xml,"//a")
# [[1]]
# <a>
#   <b> </b>
# </a> 
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLNodeSet"
```