# XML parsing using R code

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I am trying to create a data frame from a xml file. I want the data frame to look like:

```
ID   TagName   Count
1     bob        12
2     Sue        52
3     carl       15
```

This is my code so far:

```
doc<-xmlTreeParse("data.xml", useInternal = TRUE)

rootNode<-xmlRoot(doc)
```

The file looks like (I couldn't use arrows for some reason):

```
<tag>

   <row Id = "1" TagName= "bob" Count = "12" />

   <row Id = "2" TagName= "Sue" Count = "52" />

   <row Id = "3" TagName= "carl" Count= "15" />
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `xmlToList`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame

Comment: yes, I did , but I guess I am not good at pulling items out from a list. So the difficulty was for me to extract from the list that was created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(XML)
xml <- '<tag>
<row Id = "1" TagName= "bob" Count = "12" />
<row Id = "2" TagName= "Sue" Count = "52" />
<row Id = "3" TagName= "carl" Count= "15" />
</tag>'
as.data.frame(t(xpathSApply(xmlParse(xml), '/tag/*', xmlAttrs)))
#   Id TagName Count
# 1  1     bob    12
# 2  2     Sue    52
# 3  3    carl    15
```

Comment: when I try this I get: Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'