# R XML Parse for a web address

Tags: r

I am trying to download weather data, similar to the question asked here: [How to parse XML to R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame)
but when I run the first line in the example, I get "Error: 1: failed to load HTTP resource".  I've checked that the URL is valid.  Here is the line I'm referring to:

```
data <- xmlParse("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML")
```

I've managed to find a work around with the following, but would like to understand why the first line didn't work.

```
testfile <- "G:/Self Improvement/R Working Directory/test.xml"
url <- "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML"
download.file(url, testfile, mode="wb") # get data into test
data <- xmlParse(testfile)
```

Appreciate any insights.

Comment: magari è necessario che il file sia presente sul filesystem.

Comment: When that happens, try `RCurl::getURL()` to get the html at text first.  `txt <- RCurl::getURL(url)` then `data <- xmlParse(txt)` It's actually safer to just do it that way every time

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, the code returns an HTML message of Access Denied.  Here is the full message returned "<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don't have permission to access \"http&#58;&#47;&#47;forecast&#46;weather&#46;gov&#47;MapClick&#46;php&#63;\" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;8d070f17&#46;1439733211&#46;9c98310f\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the file by setting a UserAgent as follows:

```
require(httr)
UA <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36"
my_url <- "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML"
doc <- GET(my_url, user_agent(UA))
```

Now have a look at `content(doc, "text")` to see that it is the file you see in the browser

Then you can parse it via `XML` or `xml2`. I find `xml2` easier but that is just my taste. Both work.

```
data <- XML::xmlParse(content(doc, "text"))
data2 <- xml2::read_xml(content(doc, "text"))
```

**Why do i have to use a user agent?**
From the RCurl FAQ: http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html

> Why doesn't RCurl provide a default value for the useragent that some sites require?
>   This is a matter of philosophy. Firstly, libcurl doesn't specify a default value and it is a framework for others to build applications. Similarly, RCurl is a general framework for R programmers to create applications to make "Web" requests. Accordingly, we don't set the user agent either. We expect the R programmer to do this. R programmers using RCurl in an R package to make requests to a site should use the package name (and also the version of R) as the user agent and specify this in all requests.
>   Basically, we expect others to specify a meaningful value for useragent so that they identify themselves correctly.
>
> Note that users (not recommended for programmers) can set the R option named RCurlOptions via R's option() function. The value should be a list of named curl options. This is used in each RCurl request merging these values with those specified in the call. This allows one to provide default values.

I suspect http://forecast.weather.gov/ to reject all requests without a UserAgent.

Comment: So should we assume setting the UserAgent in `RCurlOptions` allow `xmlParse` to query the url directly ?

Comment: I guess so. Try it out.

Comment: I think you're mistaking me as the question OP, I'm not. I asked out of curiosity to know if this would solve the problem so future readers can have a full solution and not just a hint.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much.  Another solution I found was to use curl_fetch_memory() from the curl package.

    require(curl)
    my_url <- "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML"
    curl_data <- curl_fetch_memory(url = my_url)
    data <- rawToChar(curl_data$content)

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded this url to a text file. After that, I get the content of the file and parse it to XML data. Here is my code:

```
rm(list=ls())
require(XML)
require(xml2)
require(httr)

url <- "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML"

download.file(url=url,"url.txt" )
xmlParse(url)
data <- xmlParse("url.txt")

xml_data <- xmlToList(data)

location <- as.list(xml_data[["data"]][["location"]][["point"]])

start_time <- unlist(xml_data[["data"]][["time-layout"]][
    names(xml_data[["data"]][["time-layout"]]) == "start-valid-time"])
```

Comment: temps <- xml_data[["data"]][["parameters"]]
temps <- temps[names(temps) == "temperature"]
temps <- temps[sapply(temps, function(x) any(unlist(x) == "hourly"))]
temps <- unlist(temps[[1]][sapply(temps, names) == "value"])

Comment: out <- data.frame(
    as.list(location),
    "start_valid_time" = start_time,
    "hourly_temperature" = temps)

head(out)

Comment: Edit your answer with your comments and format it properly. I've already formatted your current post, try to do the same.

Comment: And this is just exactly what is in the Q, and thus absolutely not answering the question of why xmlParse don't work on the url.

Comment: This was the workaround posted in my original question.