# Quickly read xml file and convert to data frame

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I have an XML file Tags.xml structured like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
  <row Id="1" TagName=".net" Count="261481" ExcerptPostId="3624959" WikiPostId="3607476" />
  <row Id="2" TagName="html" Count="710104" ExcerptPostId="3673183" />
  <row Id="3" TagName="javascript" Count="1519901" ExcerptPostId="3624960" WikiPostId="3607052" />
...
</tags>
```

It's relatively well structured except that some rows are missing attributes (e.g. row 2 above is missing WikiPostId). I can convert the data into a data.table (or data.frame) with the following code

```
library(XML)
library(data.table)

# Read XML
tagsXML <- xmlParse("Tags.xml")

# Convert to List
tagsList <- xmlToList(tagsXML)

# Each List element is a character vector.  Convert each of these into a data.table
tagsList <- lapply(tagsList, function(x) as.data.table(as.list(x)))

# Rbind all the 1-row data.tables into a single data.table
tags <- rbindlist(tagsList, use.names = T, fill = T)
```

This works but seems unnecessarily slow. Is there a faster way to do this, given the well structured nature of my data?  I tried using [xpath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790925/2146894), but was unsuccessful.  For example, if I try to extract the Id values in each row with `tagsXML[["(//tags/@Id)"]]` I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For attribute-centric XML, consider the undocumented, `xmlAttrsToDataFrame`:

```
df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(tagsXML, path='//row'))

#   Id    TagName   Count ExcerptPostId WikiPostId
# 1  1       .net  261481       3624959    3607476
# 2  2       html  710104       3673183       <NA>
# 3  3 javascript 1519901       3624960    3607052
```

Comment: This is great!  Is there any way to specifically exclude certain tags?  For example, suppose ExcerptPostId has a bunch of data I don't need.  What's the best way to exclude it?

Comment: Simply remove column from final dataframe. Normally, in xpath you would run `//row/@*[name()!='ExcerptPostId']` but not in `getNodeSet()`.