# How do I parse this xml document in r?

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I am after the names of the stores and the coordinates of the stores from: http://contact.woolworths.com.au/storelocator/service/proximity/supermarkets/latitude/-37.7510/longitude/144.8981/range/50/max/200.xml

e.g.
`<name>Niddrie</name>`
`<latitude>-37.737332</latitude>`
`<longtitude>144.892342</longtitude>`

How would I do this? I have tried these:

```
library(XML)
library(methods)
library(xml2)

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame 
data <- xmlParse("http://contact.woolworths.com.au/storelocator/service/proximity/supermarkets/latitude/-37.7510/longitude/144.8981/range/50/max/200.xml")
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
location <- as.list(xml_data[["storeList"]][["storeRank"]][["storeDetail"]][["Name"]])

#https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-data-import-tutorial#xml - not working
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse("http://contact.woolworths.com.au/storelocator/service/proximity/supermarkets/latitude/-37.7510/longitude/144.8981/range/50/max/200.xml")
class(xmlfile)
topxml <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
topxml <- xmlSApply(topxml,
                    function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
xml_df <- data.frame(t(topxml),
                     row.names=NULL)
```

For both, there is no error, but not the names that I want. Same with the coordinates.

Comment: Point 21 (h) on https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/Discover/about-us/terms-and-conditions suggests this is not ethical or legal to do despite no technical control in https://www.woolworths.com.au/robots.txt unless you're using the API https://developer.woolworths.com.au/ (can you confirm that you're using the API vs scraping?)

Comment: I am scraping. Isn't that what people like us do?

Comment: I can't see a way to get that XML from scraping (only the API seems to have a "service" that returns XML). And, just because you _can_ scrape does not make ethical or legal to do so.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that XML can only come from the API. It *does* have a namespace so that's likely what's causing you problems. We'll just remove it.

```
library(xml2)

xml_ns_strip(
  doc <- read_xml("http://contact.woolworths.com.au/storelocator/service/proximity/supermarkets/latitude/-37.7510/longitude/144.8981/range/50/max/200.xml")
) -> doc

data.frame(
  name = xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, ".//storeDetail/name")),
  lng = xml_double(xml_find_all(doc, ".//storeDetail/longtitude")),
  lat = xml_double(xml_find_all(doc, ".//storeDetail/latitude")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> stores

str(stores)
## 'data.frame': 188 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ name: chr  "Niddrie" "Highpoint West" "Moonee Ponds" "East Keilor" ...
##  $ lng : num  145 145 145 145 145 ...
##  $ lat : num  -37.7 -37.8 -37.8 -37.7 -37.7 ...
```

For those still using the `XML` :

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlParse("http://contact.woolworths.com.au/storelocator/service/proximity/supermarkets/latitude/-37.7510/longitude/144.8981/range/50/max/200.xml")

def <- c(d = getDefaultNamespace(doc)[[1]]$uri)

data.frame(
  name = xpathSApply(doc, "//d:storeDetail/d:name", xmlValue, namespaces = def),
  lng = as.numeric(xpathSApply(doc, "//d:storeDetail/d:longtitude", xmlValue, namespaces = def)),
  lat = as.numeric(xpathSApply(doc, "//d:storeDetail/d:latitude", xmlValue, namespaces = def)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> stores
```