# R XML parsing to data-frame

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I have various XML files with information as shown below. Im having difficulty parsing this variable XML format into a dataframe that can handle both differing numbers of metrics and duplicated properties tags.

```
  <ProducedFruits>
    <FruitType>
      <FruitName>Apple</FruitName>
      <FruitMetrics>
        <Properties Sugars="27.51" Rate="5.03" />
        <Properties Sugars="219.39" Rate="12.19" />
        <Properties Sugars="266.34" Rate="75.9" />
      </FruitMetrics>
    </FruitType>
    <FruitType>
      <FruitName>Lime</FruitName>
      <FruitMetrics>
        <Properties Sugars="1884.2" Rate="5" />
        <Properties Sugars="1884.2" Rate="98.3" />
      </FruitMetrics>
    </FruitType>
    <FruitType>
      <FruitName>Lemon</FruitName>
      <FruitMetrics>
        <Properties Sugars="1064.77" Rate="5" />
        <Properties Sugars="1064.77" Rate="56" />
      </FruitMetrics>
    </FruitType>
    <FruitType>
      <FruitName>Banana</FruitName>
      <FruitMetrics>
        <Properties Sugars="113" Rate="12" />
        <Properties Sugars="113" Rate="79" />
      </FruitMetrics>
    </FruitType>
  </ProducedFruits>
```

Each file may be somewhat different, so ideally i would to create something that can handle the inconsistent number of values that also preserves the fruitname and creates a dataframe like the one at the bottom.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c02Oj.png)

Comment: Does this solve your problem? Pass xml data into R with `data <- XML::xmlParse("doc.xml")` then bind lists together with `XML::xml_data <- xmlToList(data)` (per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame)

Comment: @jared_mamrot yes it does! that helps tremndously, thank you!

Comment: Brilliant - I'll post it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass your xml into R as a dataframe you can use the XML package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/), e.g. `data <- XML::xmlParse("doc.xml")` then bind lists together with `xml_data <- XML::xmlToList(data)` then `xml_df <- as.data.frame(xml_data)` (per: [How to parse XML to R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame))