# Searching in a large set of characters converted from xml format

Tags: r, xml

I have converted a large xml file into characters in R and wondered if it would be possible to search for records which have specific words associated with them? Most of the information I have found on this assumes the data is in a dataframe, however mine is a lot of rows of characters, each being an entry in the xml file.

Unfortunately, I am unsure how to post XML text here and so although I know that I should not post images I am unsure how else to convey this as when I type using the XML format, the formatting disappears, but if a row of characters contains, among other things, a category called models, as in the below example, and I want to search only for models that are Sud, how would I do this? I am relatively new at using R.

[image: example XML]

Comment: Why not parse the xml: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17198658/680068

Comment: I'm looking more to find something relatively simple, along the lines of a function similar to SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE COLUMN = VALUE from SQL, is there any way to do this in R when reading/parsing an XML file?

Comment: I would parse it. Alternatively, you could try to use: `myVector[ grepl(">Sud<", myVector, fixed = TRUE) ]`

Comment: Provide example data, `dput(head(myData))`

Comment: Moved my comment into an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse it using dedicated packages, see this post: [How to parse an XML file to an R data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17198658/680068).

Alternatively, you could try to use *grepl*:

```
myVector[ grepl(">Sud<", myVector, fixed = TRUE) ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the grepl option worked wonders for me, thanks so much for your help!