# How to process output from API call in R

Tags: r, httr2

I'm trying to get data from the ECB Data Portal by sending request to the API, using [httr2 package](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/11/httr2-1-0-0/) in R.

Say I want to get EUR/USD exchange rate as in the [example on the ECB website](https://data.ecb.europa.eu/help/data-examples). I submit the following request:

```
install.packages("httr2")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(httr2)
library(tidyverse)

resp <- request("https://data-api.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/M.USD.EUR.SP00.A") %>% 
  req_perform()
```

How should I parse the response to get "clean" data in the form date-value? I've tried to do like this:

```
resp <- request("https://data-api.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/M.USD.EUR.SP00.A") %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_xml()
```

but I don't know how to further proceed with the output. Could anyone explain me what I need to do next?

I know there are other ways to get data from the ECB warehouse (e.g. [ecb package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecb/vignettes/ecb_sdw.html) that produces nice output without any processing) but I would like to know how to do it in more generic way, to be able to work with APIs for which more convenient alternative is not available. Also - I'm using httr2, but I could use Rcurl or httr instead. It doesn't matter as my problem is not with sending the request but with processing the output.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? If you call `resp_body_xml` you will get all the data as an `xml_document`. There are tons of functions for selecting data from such an object, it just all depends on what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-an-xml-file-to-an-r-data-frame for some examples. Note that the tidyverse functions use the `xml2` package for XML data rather than the older `XML` package

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, now I know that I "simply" need to parse the xml output. Somehow I didn't think about it earlier. I'll start digging into xml2. The question can be closed