# Getting bind_rows error when using xml2 and purrr to create tibbles of lists

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, xml2, tibble

My goal is to extract lists of lists from an XML file and store them as tibbles for further use. I have successfully used the `tidyverse` option described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008007/6816220), but am getting an error message for some of the lists.

I have typed the error message into my online search engine and also used the following search terms on Stack Overflow:

- map_df(flatten) bind_rows
- map_df getCharCE
- bind_rows getCharCE
- bind_rows CHARSXP

but without success of identifying a solution to my problem.

The code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(xml2)

url_deu <- "http://uwwtd.oieau.fr/Germany/sites/uwwtd.oieau.fr.Germany/files/data_sources/ekommude20145thdeploymentrelease_1475165194.xml"

dat_deu <- read_xml(url_deu)

list_deu <- as_list(dat_deu)

vector_deu <- names(list_deu$UWWTD_Report)

list_deu %>% 
  map(vector_deu[12]) %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  map_df(flatten)
```

The error message:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 'getCharCE' must be called on a CHARSXP
```

It works for most of the other list elements in `vector_deu`, see:

```
list_deu %>% 
  map(vector_deu[7]) %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  map_df(flatten)
```

First five rows of the result:

```
 # A tibble: 4,372 x 23
   aggState        repCode      aggCode           aggName aggNUTS aggLatitude aggLongitude aggGenerated
      <chr>          <chr>        <chr>             <chr>   <chr>       <chr>        <chr>        <chr>
 1        1 DE_UWWT_2014_1  DEAG_SH1000         Flensburg   DEF01     54.8049     9.446056       140000
 2        1 DE_UWWT_2014_1  DEAG_SH3000 Hansestadt Lübeck   DEF03    53.90011      10.6945       395152
 3        1 DE_UWWT_2014_1 DEAG_SH3000b    Lübeck-Priwall   DEF03    53.77016     10.85915        18317
 4        1 DE_UWWT_2014_1 DEAG_SH51001        Albersdorf   DEF05    54.14533      9.27315         4870
 5        1 DE_UWWT_2014_1 DEAG_SH51011       Brunsbüttel   DEF05    53.89388     9.180801        13886
```

I have also used unlist, which works:

```
unlist(list_deu$UWWTD_Report[12])
```

And returns the following:

```
    MSLevel.repCode MSLevel.mslSludgeProduction      MSLevel.mslWWReusePerc 
   "DE_UWWT_2014_1"                   "1463463"                         "0"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

## Session Info

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 17.04

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.7.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_CH.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_CH.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_CH.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_CH.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xml2_1.1.1      dplyr_0.7.2     purrr_0.2.2.2   readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.6.3     tibble_1.3.3   
[7] ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12     cellranger_1.1.0 compiler_3.4.1   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1        forcats_0.2.0   
 [7] tools_3.4.1      jsonlite_1.5     lubridate_1.6.0  nlme_3.1-131     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.1      psych_1.7.5      curl_2.8.1       parallel_3.4.1   haven_1.1.0     
[19] bindrcpp_0.2     stringr_1.2.0    httr_1.2.1       hms_0.3          grid_3.4.1       glue_1.1.1      
[25] R6_2.2.2         readxl_1.0.0     foreign_0.8-69   modelr_0.1.1     reshape2_1.4.2   magrittr_1.5    
[31] scales_0.4.1     rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0 mnormt_1.5-5     colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.1.5   
[37] lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.2
```

Comment: Your "problem" list example has one fewer levels of nesting than the other list, so you end up flattening it too much.  For list 12 it works to remove the intermediary `flatten` step and go directly to `map_df(flatten)`.  That list returns only a single row, which is probably why it has fewer levels of nesting.

Comment: Thank you very much! "Problem" solved.